# Spring Boot JPA unable to add custom repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I tried creating custom repository in Spring boot environment. So all my repositories can have this behavior by extending it.

TestRepository.java

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface TestRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    Object getMemberValue(Long id, String memberName);
}
```

TestRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class TestRepositoryImpl<T> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, Long> implements TestRepository<T> {
    public TestRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getMemberValue(Long id, String memberName) {
        //logic to get member value
        return null;
    }
}
```

SampleRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends TestRepository<User> {
    List<User> findByNameOrderById(String name);
}
```

Boot configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = TestRepositoryImpl.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

But application failed to start and throws below exception.

```html
2017-06-30 00:46:45.378  INFO 5408 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-30 00:46:45.529  WARN 5408 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6084d49d' of type [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFragmentsFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'repositoryFragments'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6084d49d': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepositoryImplFragment': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'testRepositoryImpl' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepositoryImpl' defined in file [D:\Workspace\Y3\EPOD_JAVA\EPOD_Boot\target\classes\com\test\repository\TestRepositoryImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation<?, ?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2017-06-30 00:46:45.529  INFO 5408 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-30 00:46:45.530  INFO 5408 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2017-06-30 00:46:45.541  INFO 5408 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2017-06-30 00:46:45.547  INFO 5408 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2017-06-30 00:46:45.553  INFO 5408 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-06-30 00:46:45.612  INFO 5408 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-06-30 00:46:46.026 ERROR 5408 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.test.repository.TestRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' in your configuration.
```

Am I missing any configuration to add custom repository?

**UPDATE**

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.test</groupId>
 <artifactId>test</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>test</name>
 <description>Test project in Spring Boot 2</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
   <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

pom.xml attached. No changes in application.properties.

Comment: your code works ok, can you show your dependencies and configuration?

Comment: @ledniov: thanks for reply. Question updated with pom.xml

Comment: For now, add `@NoRepositoryBean` to `TestRepositoryImpl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's an issue with the latest milestone of spring boot and spring data, if you switch back to `2.0.0.M1` everything works ok:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Probably it's better to report the issue to spring data team.