# Can not autowire JpaEntityInformation when extending SimpleJpaRepository of Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, repository, autowired

#### Description

JpaEntityInformation is a mandatory dependency when extending SimpleJpaRepository. Unfortunately Spring does not find this bean (although it does for EntityManager), and I don't understand why.

Please pay attention to my comment in the code of "My BaseRepository implementation", as it might be linked to the issue.

#### Error

From Intellij IDEA when hovering the dependency

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'JpaEntityInformation<T, ?>' type found.
```

From console when starting the app

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'baseRepositoryImpl' defined in file [E:\project\seed-perso\target\classes\fr\seed\perso\repository\BaseRepositoryImpl.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation<?, ?>' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

#### Configuration

I did the simpliest configuration possible.

--

Maven configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>seed-perso</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version> <!-- Current last version -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Run configuration

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
public class APIApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(APIApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My BaseRepository

```java
package fr.seed.perso.repository;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
}
```

My BaseRepository implementation

```java
package fr.seed.perso.repository;

@Repository // Should not be required because of the configuration "repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class", but without it the app start without instiating BaseRepositoryImpl, as if it was not considered a bean.
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

#### Related stack overflow questions

- [No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413707/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-org-springframework-data-jpa-repository-support-jpae)
- [Spring Boot JPA unable to add custom repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831103/spring-boot-jpa-unable-to-add-custom-repository?answertab=votes#tab-top) -> using the spring version from the accepted answer does not work.

#### Examples where it works like that

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-method-in-all-repositories
- https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-into-all-repositories/

Comment: Remove the `@Repository` as that is the actual issue (you will endup with 2 instances). The `BaseRepositoryImpl` won't be available as a bean as it will be internally used by Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. The Intellij IDEA error is very misleading, plus the fact that for some reason I do not stop in the constructor of BaseRepositoryImpl when using a breakpoint there and debugging at start up, which falsly lead me to think that BaseRepositoryImpl was not instantiated. In fact I do not stop there in my test project I wrote for this issue, but I just tested it in a real project and I DO stop at my breakpoint in the constructor...I note that in my test project no class implements BaseRepository, contrary to the real project, so it might be because of this, but weird.

Comment: It isn't misleading, because it has no way of knowing that you accidently added `@Repository` to that class.

Comment: The error also is visible without @Repository, which is the correct way and which I tried before posting this issue without realizing that my class was correctly instantiated, contrary to what the Intellij IDEA error supposed. So the "build time error" does not reflect the reality of runtime (because the bean is found and autowired), which is misleading.